# Testing flask.ext.restful url route resolution

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask

I have some flask.ext.restful application code like

```
# Providers
api.add_resource(ProvidersListAPI, '/providers',
  endpoint ='providers')
api.add_resource(ProvidersAPI, '/providers/<string:id>',
  endpoint='provider')
```

In my unit tests, I'd like to assert that for a given url the right code will be called with the right arguments from the URL.  something like:

```
with app.test_request_context('/providers/abc123') as ctx
    self.assertEqual(ctx.module_that_handles_this(), ProvidersAPI)
    self.assertEqual(flast.ext.restful.parsed_args['id'], 'abc123')
```

I've got unit tests to test the behaviour of ProvidersAPI, but what I want to test here is the resolution and mapping to different modules so that when we have a lot of routes we can be sure that some new route isn't clobbering an old route.